# WCF metadata shows incorrect service URI on HTTPS

Tags: wcf, https

Using .NET 4.7.1 and minimal WCF configuration, the WSDL, when accessed from HTTPS, shows a HTTP address, and shows the incorrect host unless port 80 is enabled in the configuration.

This service should only be available on HTTPS, which will be enforced by a firewall rule further along.

My configuration looks like this

```
<system.serviceModel>     
  <behaviors>     
    <serviceBehaviors>  
      <behavior>  
        <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="True"/>   
        <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress/>          
      </behavior>  
    </serviceBehaviors>  
  </behaviors>  
</system.serviceModel>
```

And the result looks like this in a browser (demonstrating incorrect scheme and incorrect host. Sorry that I must block out most of this, but you should be able to get what I'm saying...)

[resulting wsdl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18k5V.png)

I understand that "useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress" tells WCF that I indeed want the WSDL right next to the service. I assumed it also should be able to handle the same intentions for scheme.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was assuming I didn't need to specify binding configuration. Without binding configuration, I don't think WCF can figure out you want HTTPS bindings, and all problems flowed from there.

So, unfortunately, my web.config grows to twice its size!

```
      <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SecureServiceBinding" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="20480000" maxBufferSize="10240000" maxReceivedMessageSize="10240000" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true" messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="100" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```